# Session Cookies Only for Specific Routes

Tags: session, cookies, node.js, express

I'm using Connect.js and the connect-session module for managing session cookies. I noticed that Connect sets a session cookie on all routes except static files. The problem is that I process some static files like JS and CSS files before I send them so I can't use Connect's built-in static server, which means that connect-session sets a session cookie for these files. Since these files will be included on external sites, I don't want them to send cookies with them.

Is it possible to set session cookies only for specific routes?

Comment: `app.use('/session-only', express.session());` should work.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/307) might interest you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I found my answer here: http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html

You can ignore routes by using connect.session.ignore like so: `connect.session.ignore.push('/robots.txt');`

Comment: Not anymore: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/commit/73bf05479cee5b7e8e4e7ba27b45be16a303c912#lib/middleware/session.js

Comment: Suppose you could get the session middleware in a variable, `var session = express.session({ key: 'blah' });` and then just write a middleware that calls `session.apply(express, arguments)` on paths you want the session middleware

Answer (score 3):

if you are using express,you can put `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` before `app.use(express.session());`.